# Proof by induction factorial

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, recreational-mathematics

For $m, n ∈ \Bbb N, m ≥ 1$, let $S(m, n)$ be the number of solutions to the equation:
$x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_m = n$, where $x_i ∈ \Bbb N$ for $i = 1, \ldots , m$.
Using induction, prove that for all, $m, n \in\Bbb N, m ≥ 1$,
$$S(m, n) = \frac{(n + m − 1)!}{(m − 1)!\,n!}$$

I am unable to solve this question, any contribution is highly appreciated.

Comment: Case work on whether or not $x_m$ is $0$ gives an inductive formula.

Comment: I don't get what you mean by case work.

Comment: Hint: you can do it _without_ induction using [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)#Theorem_one_proof), but you can adapt that proof, together with [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Recursive_formula), to induct instead. @KentaS's comment refers to this strategy; it relates to how the recursion is proved.

Comment: In theorem 2, it has value to what the equation is equal to. I am sorry @J.G. but I really don't understand the combination of the two ways you linked.

Comment: There is a problem with your posting.  I regard your responses to the comments as **very reasonable**.  For a Math student, new to the topic, the entire topic can be confusing if not overwhelming.  However, MathSE reviewers are not actually allowed to provide a clear answer to your Math problem, despite how reasonable your confusion is, because of MathSE protocol.  See next comment.

Comment: Please see [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).
  In particular, please see the **Edit-Tools** section of the article, and the portion of the article that discusses *showing work*.  For the specific Math problem that you have posted, it is expected that you will edit your posting to make a significant attempt to solve the problem, after detailing what training you have been provided (i.e. what **tools** you have been given).

Comment: It doesn't matter how successful your attempt is.  What matters is that you followed the protocol.